# Are there any known triggers for Avenatti deciding not to run for presidency?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, democratic-party

According to [Michael Avenatti, After Flirting With Run, Says He Won’t Seek White House](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/04/us/politics/michael-avenatti-president.html), Avenatti announced that he wasn't running for presidency on Tuesday 4 December. The NYT article mentions his arrest a few weeks ago on suspicion of domestic violence. The article also mentions his recommendation in October that a *"white male"* be the Democratic Nominee in 2020, but I didn't notice anything more recent than a couple of weeks ago.

Have there been any recent publicly known events that could have triggered his decision not to run for presidency?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it is off topic for politics.se; it is beyond our scope to delve into his mind.

Comment: @DrunkCynic, this question is not about the internal motivation of people; it seems more about factual, verifiable event: whether or not a public person has publicly referred to a publicly known event to be a reason for his/her decision.

Comment: Perhaps, if both the arrest and accusation were well-founded, that Avenatti correctly feared that under the national scrutiny of a campaign his formerly undiscovered errors would be unlikely to remain concealed, thus inspiring general disapproval.

Comment: This question assumes that Avenatti was seriously considering running for President. But AFAIK he had neither previous political experience, support base, nor even name recognition/money to support such a move. After seeing some of his antics, I am convinced (of course this is just a personal opinion) that the whole "flirting with run" was little more than an attempt of getting free publicity, he has done some of those (to put things into context, not so much time ago he was trying to sell the idea of a TV talk show hosted by him and former WH speakerperson Anthony Scaramucci).

Comment: @SJuan76 - i had the impression that 538 crew seriously considered him as possible (if not necessarily effective) contender but don't have time to fine a citation

Comment: @SJuan76 many of those things didn’t stop Trump!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the recent indictment might be a clue. According to [the Los Angeles Times](https://www.latimes.com/politics/la-na-pol-avenatti-indicted-fraud-theft-charges-20190411-story.html) (you really need to read the full article to get all the details, e.g. relating to his race-car team and his private jet):

> In a sweeping expansion of the criminal charges against Michael Avenatti, a federal grand jury has indicted the Los Angeles lawyer on 36 counts of fraud, perjury, failure to pay taxes, embezzlement and other financial crimes.
>
> [...]
>
> In a separate federal case in New York, Avenatti faces up to 47 more years if convicted on charges of trying to extort more than $20 million from Nike, the sportswear giant. An indictment in that case is expected soon.

While this information wasn't known to the public before, I can see how Avenatti might have known that this would come out sooner had he decided to run for office.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned an enormous one. He proclaimed himself a defender of women then had a somewhat credible accusation of [physically abusing a woman](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/2018/11/14/michael-avenatti-arrested-following-domestic-violence-incident/2006582002/). He also seems to have some serious [financial issues within his law firm](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2018/11/17/michael-avenatti-law-firm-evicted-after-not-paying-more-than-back-rent/). There are also numerous accusations of legal malpractice at this point. One coming from Stormy Daniels, which may or may not be true, that he [sued Trump on her behalf without her consent](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/politics-news/stormy-daniels-says-michael-avenatti-sued-trump-defamation-against-her-n941446). He has been facing an [investigation by the California Bar](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/michael-avenatti-being-investigated-by-california-state-bar) for possibly unethical behavior. In addition to that he has been [referred by the Judicial Committee](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/25/us/politics/grassley-avenatti-brett-kavanaugh.html) for investigation over his role in the Kavanaugh hearings.

After all of these landmines that would almost certainly be used to attack him during the primaries combined with his recent comments about how the party should be run by a [white male inflaming some elements within the party](https://www.cnn.com/2018/10/25/politics/michael-avenatti-time/index.html) it would be highly unlikely he could raise the funding or get the backing otherwise to wage a serious effort to win the primaries.

Comment: How recent were these issues?